# List Disk in diskpart but exclude removable drive

Tags: batch-file, findstr

Is it possible to list only Fixed Disks when using Diskpart? Here is a line from my script that I am writing. Problem is that the below command lists all disks. Even Removable USB sticks. I need it to exclude the USB. (Only exclude it not remove it, my script will still need to access files from it later) 
I will eventually have a Prompt for a user asking to select a fixed drive, so I would like to have a list of the drives so the user can choose.

```
echo list disk | diskpart | findstr /b /c:" "
```

Comment: There are other ways of listing the drives in a computer without resorting to using the very dangerous administrator tool, `diskpart`. Are you only wanting two lists; one with all drives and one with fixed only; one with all drives and one with all drives except removable; one with only fixed and removable and one with only fixed.

Comment: hey thanks. I am actually wanting to list only fixed drives. Its for a winpe script. I need to format and then install windows. Sometimes there is more than one drive. I realize that there are other ways. For eg. wmic   But was wondering if there is a way to do this with diskpart? Most of my script is with diskpart. I just got stuck now because when there is one drive my script still thinks there is two. Which is the usb.

Comment: If you are running the WinPE script from a USB drive then the USB drive letter is known, _(it's the drive letter of that script path, `%~d0`)._

Comment: So there is no way to skip USB detection with a filter or something within the line of code I posted?